# anchor tag is not working with image http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/demo.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

actully i m trying to use anchor tag with this slider image

```
<div class="smallsliderdiv">

<p class="smallslider"> Top websites </p>

<div id="makeMeScrollable">

<a href="google.com"><img width="400px" height="300px" src="g1.jpg"/></a>
<a href="fb.com"><img width="400px" height="300px" src="g2.jpg"/></a>
<a href="android.com"><img width="400px" height="300px" src="g3.jpg"/></a>
<img width="400px" height="300px" src="k1.jpg"/>
<img width="400px" height="300px" src="k2.jpg"/>

</div> 
<div>
```

but its not working images are not getting showed when i do like this? i dont want the alternative way .. what is the problem with this slider?? last two images have no problem .. when i remove anchor tag all is fine but i need this. Thank you.

**This is working fine with html but not with the slider i m using which is http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/demo.html use js and css from this site**
and i am using for each loop for echoing image address and link address .

Comment: See fiddle, it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/46/  most likely an issue with targeting the <img> or your css and javascript, please add the css and the what type of slider you are using

Comment: This is working fine with html but not with the slider i m using which is http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/demo.html use js and css from this site

Comment: can you show you initialized it?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, since your .js or .css slider files probably has an issue with wrapping the images with an anchor tag, so instead of wrapping the images with an anchor you can add an onclick event to the img and have the javascript link the image. and manually change the cursor to a pointer in the CSS.

See fiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/47/

html

```
<img onclick="image1()" width="400px" height="300px" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/>
```

CSS

```
#makeMeScrollable > img:hover{
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Javascript

```
function image1(){
window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
}
```

Comment: this is working but i want anchor tag should work .. is there any way i can make it work? the standard way?

Comment: @AniketKarne not without changing the css or javascript slider files. And I really think it will be harder to do, you can give me all the css and javascript files and I can take a look at it for you, if you like.

Comment: no no i change js and css but i want anchor tag nd image tag together don't want to mess with that :-)